# Flutter/Dart setState are not refreshing the Text in Text Widget

Tags: json, flutter, dart, refresh, setstate

I want to refresh my Text "ganzerchat" but it dont works with how i do it

thats my Chat Class (StatefulWidget) i tryed with setstate but nothing happens everytime.

I opened the Chat from the main.dart

List chatverlauf = [];

```
Future getDataFromYourApi() async {
  List<String> tmp = [];
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

  chatverlauf.clear();
  ganzerChat = "";

  extractedData.forEach((id, data) {
    tmp.add(data["name"] + ": " + data["text"]);
    //print(data["name"] + ": " + data["text"]);
    
  });
  return tmp;
}

Future<void> loadChat() async{
  
  chatverlauf = await getDataFromYourApi();
  

  setState(() {
    ganzerChat = chatverlauf.join("\n");
    print(ganzerChat);
  });
}


return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Chat"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child:
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 50),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Text(
            ganzerChat,
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          )),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: TextField(controller: eingabecontroller)),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Senden"),
            onPressed:()async{
              await loadChat();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

}

maybe anyone here have the same problem and can help me

Comment: Please don't post post screenshots of code/errors https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: You need to share your code directly on StackOverflow. Not screenshots of it.

Comment: how can share it directly?

Comment: Just copy paste your code into your question. And do not write an answer as a comment.

Comment: Is your data loading when you call `getDataFromYourApi()`?

Comment: yes it loads a String the problem is the string are not refreshing on the Text Widget

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was because I had the methods below the Widget build. I put it above then it worked!

Sorry for the time waste, I thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new function to set chatverlauf values. Something like this: **getDataFromYourApi()**:

```
Future<void> loadChat() async{
    ganzerChat = "";
    chatverlauf = await getDateFromYourApi();

    for(int i=0;i<chatverlauf.lenght;i++){
        ganzerChat = ganzerChat + chatverlauf[i] + "\n";
    }
    setState(() {
       ganzerChat = ganzerChat + "";
    });

}
```

In your ElevatedButton:

```
ElevatedButton(
   child: Text("Senden"),
   onPressed: ()async{
      await loadChat();
   }
),
```

Comment: It dont works. Maybe i have any other problems but im new with this language i trying to fix this now 4 hours long

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `for` cycle to join the `array` of `Strings`. Just do a `join` with the `\n` as the separator:

```
setState(() {
  ganzerChat = chatverlauf.join("\n")
});
```

Comment: i tryed this too now but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Now, in the function **getDataFromYourApi()** try this:

```
Future <List<String>> getDataFromYourApi() async {
  ...
  
}
```

Comment: not working maybe it help if you show the image that i posted under this from my statefull widget